Typescript doesn't read environment variables correctly in an aws cdk triggered from a gitlab ci
I add the variables here in the pipeline
variables:
    URL_ORIGIN: "url"

it echos successfully
script:
    - echo "URL_ORIGIN_VALUE $URL_ORIGIN"

but when I read it in typescript it is never defined
const urlOrigin = process.env["URL_ORIGIN"];

It needs to be an environment variable because it will change from environment to the other

And this only happens with AWS CDK?

I don’t know. I only use typescript with AWS CDK.

You will need to add more details and/or a reproducible example. The provided info is not enough - the issue must lie elsewhere. For starters, can you post a complete minimal gitlab-ci.yml file?

As suggested by @gshpychka we would need more context. A common issue with envs and gitlab is also the variable scope (protected vs unprotected)

I turns out when you need to read an environment variable in typescript. you must or it with a string or something. or it doesn't work.
const urlOrigin = process.env["URL_ORIGIN"]|| 'not-defined';

